# Tag Names As Variables And Displaying It In Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, loops, user-interface, tags, matlab-figure

I’m building a GUI in Matlab (my first one), I have 160 static text boxes with the tag name “tag_matrix_1, tag_matrix_2, etc”. I’m trying to build a loop that puts all the tag names in a vector:

```
for i = 1:160
tagNames(i) = ['tag_matrix_' num2str(i)];
end
```

But I’ll always get the error: “In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.”
Why? And how do I fix it?

My second question is about displaying it in a loop. Is it possible to loop it, so I don’t have 160 lines of setting up my static text boxes?
Like:

```
for i = 1:160
set(handles."how can I implement tagNames(i) in there",'String',data2d(i,:);
end
```

Comment: For the 1st question: All the `tagNames` do not have the same # of characters (eg. `tag_matrix_1` vs `tag_matrix_160`) so you get the error about dimensions. You would be better off using a cell array to store them, i.e. `tagNames{i}`. Or use structures with dynamic name referencing.

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd question; what is wrong with the loop to set up the name displayed in the text boxes?

Comment: First of all thanks. tagNames{i} works great. I don't know how i would put the variable into my line: set(handles.tagName{i},'String',data2d(i,:)); doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to store the tag names in an array (this will fail because they are all different sizes), I would create a struct where the fieldname is the tag name and the value is the handle itself. You can use dynamic field referencing for this.

```
for k = 1:160
    field = ['tag_matrix_', num2str(k)];
    myhandles.(field) = findobj(gcf, 'tag', field);
end
```

Then in your second loop (to fill in the values), you'd access the fields of this struct.

```
for k = 1:160
    set(myhandles.(['tag_matrix_', num2str(k)]), 'String', data2d(k,:));
end
```

Do you actually need to store the `tag_names` like that? You can actually just use `findobj` to find the element with a given tag. This would allow you to replace the second loop with.

```
for k = 1:160
    set(findobj(gcf, 'tag', ['tag_matrix_', num2str(k)]), 'String', data2d(k,:))
end
```